# Creating new DocuSign recipients and assigning recipient Type

Tags: integration, developer, docusign

I am trying to create a recipient and want the recepient type to be "Receives a Copy (Carbon Copy)" or "Allow to Edit(Editor)" but the receiver still gets assigned the type "Signer". Below is the code I am using

```
dfsle.Recipient myRecipient = dfsle.Recipient.fromSource(
    user.Name, // Recipient name
    user.Email, // Recipient email
    null, // optional phone #
    'editor', 
    new dfsle.Entity(currentRecordId));
```

Comment: You will need to contact Docusign support.

Answer (score 0):

To add a cc recipient you have to add a type like this:

```
dfsle.Recipient myRecipient = dfsle.Recipient.fromSource(
user.Name, // Recipient name
user.Email, // Recipient email
null, // optional phone #
'editor', 
new dfsle.Entity(currentRecordId)); 

myRecipient = myRecipient.withType('CarbonCopy');
```

Have you tried 'Editor' instead of 'editor'?